# Unable to see mathematical expressions in comments sections. But it is visible in answer section. (Problem is arising in the Stack Exchange iOS app)

Tags: support, ios-app

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 11.2.5 (Build 15D60)

Comment: What do you see instead (plain text with `$` symbols, `code` format, error icons)? Which sites are you using (Math or Physics or...)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887742/what-is-the-significance-of-limit-of-a-function-not-existing#comment5963512_2887742

Comment: I am using mathematics site.

Comment: Yes I see the code formats. $ symbols.

Comment: Actually now I got the solution for this problem. There is an option ‘ render MathJax ‘ , which converts these into mathematical symbols. Thank you.

Comment: @user35122 Can you please post that as a self-answer?

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be solved by using an option ‘ Render MathJax ‘ in comment section.